# Snake-like console game

Tags: c++, beginner, game, console

This is what I came up with when trying to make my first console game. I think it turned out quite okay so I wanted to know what you think about it.
If there is anything to improve, may it be coding style, readability, efficiency or anything else, please let me know.

### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "game.h"


int main()
{
    bool exit = false;

    std::cout   << "Controls:\n"
                << " - Use w, a, s, d to change direction.\n"
                << " - Press space to pause the game.\n\n";
    system("pause");
    system("cls");

    while( !exit )
    {
        size_t hight = 20, width = 20;

        Game game(hight , width);
        game.StartGame();
        while( !game.isGameOver )
        {
            game.Update();
            Sleep( 100 );
        }

        std::cout << "\nGame Over.\nPress 1 to play again.\nPress Esc to exit.";
        char input = 0;
        while( input != '1' && input != 27 )
        {
            input = getch();
        }

        if( input == 27)
            exit = true;

        system("cls");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### field.h

```
#ifndef FIELD_H
#define FIELD_H

#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

class Field
{
public:
    // Constructor & Destructor
    Field( size_t hight, size_t width );
    ~Field();

    // Methods
    void Draw();

    // Members
    char **field;
    enum BlockType{ EMPTY = ' ', WALL = '#', FOOD = '*', sHEAD = 2, sBODY = 'o' };

private:
    size_t HIGHT;
    size_t WIDTH;
};



#endif // FIELD_H
```

### field.cpp

```
#include "field.h"

Field::Field( size_t hight, size_t width )
 : field( nullptr ), HIGHT( hight ), WIDTH( width )
{
    //  allocate field array
    field = new char* [HIGHT];

    for( size_t i = 0;  i < HIGHT; i++)
    {
        field[i] = new char[WIDTH];
    }

    // initialize field array
    for( size_t i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++ )
        field[0][i] = field[HIGHT - 1][i] = WALL;    // first and last line are borders

    for( size_t i = 1; i < HIGHT - 1; i++ )
    {
        field[i][0] = field[i][WIDTH - 1] = WALL;
        for( size_t j = 1; j < WIDTH - 1; j++ )     // first and last column are borders
        {
            field[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
}

Field::~Field()
{
    for( size_t i = 0; i < HIGHT; i++)
    {
        delete [] field[i];
    }

    delete [] field;
}

void Field::Draw()
{
    for( size_t i = 0; i < HIGHT; i++)
    {
        for( size_t j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
        {
            putch(field[i][j]);
        }
        putch('\n');
    }
}
```

### snake.h

```
#ifndef SNAKE_H
#define SNAKE_H

#include <iostream>

class Snake
{
public:
    // Constructor & Destructor
    Snake( size_t MaxLength, size_t pos_x, size_t pos_y );
    ~Snake();

    // Members
    enum Direction{ UP = 'w', DOWN = 's', LEFT = 'a', RIGHT = 'd', UNDIRECTED };

    size_t **snake;
    size_t length;
    Direction direction;
    size_t temp_TailPosition[2];

    // Methods
    void ChangeDirection( Direction dir );
    void Move();
    void Grow();

private:
    size_t maxLength;
};


#endif // SNAKE_H
```

### snake.cpp

```
#include "snake.h"

Snake::Snake( size_t MaxLength, size_t pos_x, size_t pos_y )
 : length( 3 ), direction( UNDIRECTED ), maxLength( MaxLength )
{
    // Allocate snake array
    snake = new size_t *[maxLength];

    for( size_t i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
    {
        snake[i] = new size_t [2];
    }

    // Initialize snake array
    for( size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        snake[i][0] = pos_x;
        snake[i][1] = pos_y;
    }

    // Initialize temp_TailPosition
    temp_TailPosition[0] = pos_x;
    temp_TailPosition[1] = pos_y;
}

Snake::~Snake()
{
    for( size_t i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
    {
        delete [] snake[i];
    }

    delete [] snake;
}

void Snake::ChangeDirection( Direction dir )
{
    switch( dir )
    {
    case UP:
        if( direction != DOWN )
            direction = UP;
        break;

    case DOWN:
        if( direction != UP )
            direction = DOWN;
        break;

    case LEFT:
        if( direction != RIGHT )
            direction = LEFT;
        break;

    case RIGHT:
        if( direction != LEFT )
            direction = RIGHT;
        break;

    case UNDIRECTED:
        break;
    }
}

void Snake::Move()
{
    if( direction == UNDIRECTED )
        return;

    // Remember tail position
    temp_TailPosition[0] = snake[length - 1][0];
    temp_TailPosition[1] = snake[length - 1][1];

    // Move Body
    for( size_t i = length - 1; i > 0; i-- )
    {
        snake[i][0] = snake[i - 1][0];
        snake[i][1] = snake[i - 1][1];
    }

    // Move Head
    switch( direction )
    {
    case UP:
        snake[0][1] -= 1;
        break;

    case DOWN:
        snake[0][1] += 1;
        break;

    case LEFT:
        snake[0][0] -= 1;
        break;

    case RIGHT:
        snake[0][0] += 1;
        break;
    }
}

void Snake::Grow()
{
    length++;
    snake[length - 1][0] = temp_TailPosition[0];
    snake[length - 1][1] = temp_TailPosition[1];
}
```

### game.h

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     // srand, rand
#include <time.h>       //  time

#include "snake.h"
#include "field.h"

class Game
{
public:
    Game( size_t hight, size_t width );


    // Members
    bool isGameOver;


    // Methods
    void StartGame();
    char GetInput();
    Snake::Direction GetDirection( char input );
    void Update();
    void Draw();

private:
    // Members
    Field FIELD;
    Snake SNAKE;
    size_t HIGHT;
    size_t WIDTH;
    size_t score;

    // Methods
    void SpawnFood();
    void PutSnake();
    void MoveCurser( size_t x, size_t y );
    void GameOver();
    void Pause();
};



#endif // GAME_H
```

### game.cpp

```
#include "game.h"

Game::Game( size_t hight, size_t width )
 : isGameOver( false ),
   FIELD( hight, width ),
   SNAKE( hight * width, width / 2, hight / 2),
   HIGHT( hight ),
   WIDTH( width ),
   score( 0 )
{
    // Put Head
    size_t &headPos_x = SNAKE.snake[0][0];
    size_t &headPos_y = SNAKE.snake[0][1];

    FIELD.field[headPos_y][headPos_x] = Field::BlockType::sHEAD;

    // Generate random seed
    srand(time(NULL));

    // Spawn Food
    SpawnFood();
}

void Game::StartGame()
{
    Draw();
    char input = 0;

    while( input != 'w' && input != 'a' && input != 's' && input != 'd' )
    {
        input = GetInput();
    }

    Snake::Direction direction = GetDirection( input );
    SNAKE.ChangeDirection( direction );
    SNAKE.Move();
    PutSnake();
    Draw();
}

char Game::GetInput()
{
    if( kbhit() == true )
    {
        char input = getch();
        return input;
    }

    return 0;
}

Snake::Direction Game::GetDirection( char input )
{
    switch(input)
    {
    case 'w':
        return Snake::Direction::UP;

    case 'a':
        return Snake::Direction::LEFT;

    case 's':
        return Snake::Direction::DOWN;

    case 'd':
        return Snake::Direction::RIGHT;

    default:
        return Snake::Direction::UNDIRECTED;
    }
}

void Game::Update()
{
    char input = GetInput();
    if( input == ' ' )
        Pause();
    Snake::Direction direction = GetDirection( input );
    SNAKE.ChangeDirection( direction );
    SNAKE.Move();
    PutSnake();
    Draw();
}

void Game::Draw()
{
    MoveCurser( 0, 0 );
    FIELD.Draw();
    std::cout << "Score: " << score;
}

void Game::SpawnFood()
{
    size_t  x = 0,
            y = 0;
    while( FIELD.field[y][x] != Field::BlockType::EMPTY )
    {
        x = rand() % WIDTH;
        y = rand() % HIGHT;
    }

    FIELD.field[y][x] = Field::BlockType::FOOD;
}

void Game::PutSnake()
{
    size_t &headPos_x = SNAKE.snake[0][0];
    size_t &headPos_y = SNAKE.snake[0][1];
    size_t &oldTailPos_x = SNAKE.temp_TailPosition[0];
    size_t &oldTailPos_y = SNAKE.temp_TailPosition[1];


    switch( FIELD.field[headPos_y][headPos_x])
    {
    case Field::BlockType::FOOD:
        SNAKE.Grow();
        score++;

        FIELD.field[headPos_y][headPos_x] = Field::BlockType::sHEAD;        // Put Head
        for( size_t i = 1; i < SNAKE.length; i++ )                          // Put Body
        {
            FIELD.field[SNAKE.snake[i][1]][SNAKE.snake[i][0]] = Field::BlockType::sBODY;
        }

        SpawnFood();
        break;

    case Field::BlockType::EMPTY:
        FIELD.field[oldTailPos_y][oldTailPos_x] = Field::BlockType::EMPTY;  // Remove old Tail
        FIELD.field[headPos_y][headPos_x] = Field::BlockType::sHEAD;        // Put Head

        for( size_t i = 1; i < SNAKE.length; i++ )                          // Put Body
        {
            FIELD.field[SNAKE.snake[i][1]][SNAKE.snake[i][0]] = Field::BlockType::sBODY;
        }
        break;

    case Field::BlockType::WALL:
    case Field::BlockType::sBODY:
        isGameOver = true;
        GameOver();
        break;
    }
}

void Game::MoveCurser( size_t x, size_t y )
{
    HANDLE hOut;
    COORD position;

    hOut = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );

    position.X = x;
    position.Y = y;

    SetConsoleCursorPosition( hOut, position);
}

void Game::GameOver()
{
    size_t &oldHeadPos_x = SNAKE.snake[1][0];
    size_t &oldHeadPos_y = SNAKE.snake[1][1];

    for( char i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
    {
        MoveCurser( oldHeadPos_x, oldHeadPos_y);
        putch(Field::BlockType::sHEAD);
        Sleep(150);
        MoveCurser( oldHeadPos_x, oldHeadPos_y);
        putch(Field::BlockType::EMPTY);
        Sleep(150);
    }
}

void Game::Pause()
{
    system("cls");
    std::cout << "Game paused.\nPress space to continue.";
    char input = 0;
    while( input != ' ')
    {
        input = getch();
    }
    system("cls");
    Draw();
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I have found a couple of things that could help you improve your code.

### Don't use `system("cls")`

There are two reasons not to use `system("cls")` or `system("pause")`.  The first is that it is not portable to other operating systems which you may or may not care about now.  The second is that it's a security hole, which you absolutely **must** care about.  Specifically, if some program is defined and named `cls` or `pause`, your program will execute that program instead of what you intend, and that other program could be anything.  First, isolate these into a seperate functions `cls()` and `pause()` and then modify your code to call those functions instead of `system`.  Then rewrite the contents of those functions to do what you want using C++.  For example, if your terminal supports [ANSI Escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), you could use this:

```
void cls()
{
    std::cout << "\x1b[2J";
}
```

### Isolate platform-specific code

In this code, there are several things that are DOS/Windows only including `#include <conio.h>` and the `getch()` and `kbhit()` functions within that, and also `system("cls");` that I've already mentioned.  Your code runs successfully on Linux if I supply those missing functions, but it would be nice if there were an `#ifdef WINDOWS` already in the code so that one could recompile without having to alter the source code.

### Consider using a better random number generator

You are currently using

```
x = rand() % WIDTH;
```

There are problems with this approach. One is that the low order bits of the random number generator are not particularly random, so neither is `x`.  On my machine, there's a slight but measurable bias toward 0 with that.  A better solution, if your compiler and library supports it, would be to use the [C++11 `std::uniform_int_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution).  It looks complex, but it's actually pretty easy to use.  Here's an example:

```
unsigned rand_uint(unsigned low, unsigned high)
{
    static std::default_random_engine re{};
    using Dist = std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned>;
    static Dist uid{};
    return uid(re, Dist::param_type{low,high});
}
```

### Eliminate "magic numbers"

There are a few numbers in the code, such as `20` and `27` that have a specific meaning in their particular context.  By using named constants such as `WIDTH` or `ESC`, the program becomes easier to read and maintain.

### Use correct spellings

The word "height" is misspelled as "hight" throughout the program.  It's not a major point but it makes your code harder for others to use and understand if common words are not spelled correctly.

### Use `const` where practical

The `hight` and `width` variables in `main.cpp` are never altered in the program and should be declared as `const`.  Similarly, member functions that don't alter the underlying object, such as `Field::Draw()` should be declared as `const`.

### Separate class responsibilities more completely

The `Game` class reaches into the `Snake` class and directly manipulates `Snake` member variables.  This is a sign that the classes are not as well designed as they could be.  Specifically, it seems that much of the code that is currently in `Game::PutSnake()` should be delegated instead to the `Snake` object. To take another specific example, consider rewriting the `Game::SpawnFood()` function to eliminate the need for direct access to the `field` member data:

```
void Game::SpawnFood()
{
    size_t  x = 0,
            y = 0;
    while( !FIELD.isEmpty(x,y) )
    {
        x = rand_uint(0, WIDTH);
        y = rand_uint(0, HIGHT);
    }
    FIELD.dropFood(x, y);
}
```

### Carefully separate interface from implementation

The `#include` files that you put into a `.h` file are a part of its interface, while the ones in the corresponding `.cpp` file are part of the implementation.  So for instance, `conio.h` is not required to understand and use the interface for `Field` and so that `#include` should not appear in the `field.h` file.  It should instead be put into the `field.cpp` file since it's a detail of the implementation and not of the interface.

### Omit `return 0`

When a C++ program reaches the end of `main` the compiler will automatically generate code to return 0, so there is no reason to put `return 0;` explicitly at the end of `main`.

Comment: Minor quibble: the reason for putting `return 0;` at the end of `main` is that without it the code looks wrong. <g> It's a weird special case, intended to make it easier to teach absolute beginners. But part of what it teaches has to be unlearned when writing any other value-returning function. Personally, I always put it in `main`. But I don't disagree with people who leave it out.

Comment: @PeteBecker It's been a part of the standard since 1999.  Some people don't know about it, others do but don't like it.  Like you, I don't feel that strongly about it, but my practice is to always omit it.

Comment: This little bit of tautological madness will make use of the high bits of `rand()`s result to give a better distribution of values: `(rand() % ((RAND_MAX / WIDTH)*WIDTH))/(RAND_MAX / WIDTH)`. It determines the largest possible multiple of `WIDTH` that will fit inside the range of `rand` and multiplies by that before taking the modules. This means the range of values used is much larger. Then a quantization step is applied to get the correct range of values. [Example](http://ideone.com/CrJNcl).

Comment: Or if you want to go the floating point route: `int(rand()/(std::nexttoward(RAND_MAX, std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity())*WIDTH)`.

Comment: @Edward Thanks a lot for your feedback! I will try to apply all of that. I have some questions though:
How could I handle the input without the `getch()` and `kbhit()` functions?
How do I use `#ifdef WINDOWS` to make the code compile on other platforms?
Is it possible to do something like `char c = 'a';` for the Esc character or is it necessary to do something like `#define ESC 27` `char c = ESC;`?

Comment: One can use a [Linux-based `conio.h` replacement](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linux-conioh/) but I would advocate instead putting all such platform-specific code into a single module.  For constants, you can use `static const char ESC = 27;` which is better than a `#define` because it has a specified type.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use raw pointers for your arrays. Instead use `std::vector`, which is no less efficient but much less prone to errors.

Additionally, to implement a 2D array, you should use a single array and do arithmetic to find the index instead of using an array of arrays.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>     bool exit = false;
> ```

If you get rid of that line and change

> ```
>     while( !exit )
> ```

to

```
    while ( true )
```

And then change

> ```
>         while( input != '1' && input != 27 )
>         {
> ```

to

```
        while ( input != '1' )
        {
            if ( input == 27 )
            {
                return EXIT_SUCCESS;
            }
```

You can get rid of the repetitive

> ```
>         if( input == 27)
>             exit = true;
> ```

You could also say `break` rather than `return EXIT_SUCCESS`, but I find this more direct in this case.

I would also agree with changing `27` to a constant but that's outside the point that I was making.

You may also want to clear the screen before returning.  Since I switched to the block form of the `if`, that's as simple as adding a single line.